# rotate function not working in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer

The following code is working in all browsers but not in Internet Explorer, even though I used MsTransform but still it is not working.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
var looper;
var degrees = 0;
function rotateAnimation(el,speed){
 var elem = document.getElementById(el);
    elem.style.WebkitTransform = "rotate("+degrees+"deg)";
    elem.style.MozTransform = "rotate("+degrees+"deg)";
    elem.style.MsTransform = "rotate("+degrees+"deg)";
    elem.style.OTransform = "rotate("+degrees+"deg)";
looper = 
setTimeout(function()
{
    rotateAnimation(el,speed)
},speed);

    degrees++;
     if(degrees > 359){
         degrees = 1;
    }
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<img id="img1" src="cog1.png" alt="cog1">
<script>rotateAnimation("img1",30);</script>
</body>  
</html>
```

Comment: Try with `elem.style.msTransform` and adding `elem.style.transform`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try lowercase:

```
elem.style.msTransform = "rotate("+degrees+"deg)";
```

[Working Link](http://jsbin.com/xozemorima/1/)